# Endpoint registration in REST web service constructor gives error

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I've written a REST web service which then makes calls to web.py. I need to register certain endpoints in its constructor. On doing that, it gives me Servlet.init error (500).
Find my code below. Is this the right way to do it? If not, is how can I write an init() function?

Here is my code:

```
@Path("/xyz/api")
public class Service {
Extensions ext = new Extensions();
String parentUrl = "http://10.112.1.2";

Service() {
    ext.logInformation("managedEntity");        // call to register endpoint
    parentUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
}

@POST
@Path("/doSomething/{input}")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String createNetwork(@PathParam("input") String input) {

    try {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        PostMethod method = new PostMethod(parentUrl + "/doSomething?input=" + input);

        method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
                new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

        try {
            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
            }
            byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
            System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
        } catch (HttpException e) {
            System.err.println("Fatal protocol violation: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Fatal transport error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
        } 
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return result.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: can u show me your URL that u making call?

Comment: While u Calling same URL from that method again just try to print that whole url might be it wont take http://localhost:8080 according to me. just try to print it and debug it where is the exception thrown.

Comment: The constructor is causing the error, if I comment that out, everything works fine

Comment: okey try to replace this instead of that. http ://localhost:8080/xyz/api let me know if it works

Comment: Try making the constructor `public`

Comment: @peeskillet, Worked!
silly mistake!